# The computational complexity of lagrange multiplier(fmincon) in matlab

Tags: computational-complexity

There is a function in Matlab called "fmincon()". Currently, I need to solve a lagrange multiplier problem which can be solved by fmincon() function. However, the  number of constrain is quite high and the constrains are nonlinear. The problem looks like this:

$\min _{c^{\prime}}\left\|c^{\prime}-c\right\|^{2}$

s.t. $\left\|x_{i}-c\right\|^{2} \leqslant d_{i},$ $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$

In which the vector $c$, $x_{i}$ and the scalar $d_{i}$ are given, and I want to find $c^{\prime}$.

Now, the number of constrains $n$ may be quite large. I am wondering the computational complexity of that function regarding to the number and the complexity of constrains. Or just the time complexity of solving a lagrange multiplier problem.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question in order to present an answer, because we don't know what your nonlinear constraints look like, and what does your target function to be optimized look like. It is like asking: I have a big piece of metal with wings: how fast will it fly? ( without specifying anything else.)

Comment: This is an absolutely model problem to solve with a second-order cone solver (SOCP) instead of a general nonlinear optimizer.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The econd order problem is one kind of problem I need to solve. But I also encounter problems with exponential function constrain.

Comment: If your problem is still convex then it can likely be solved with one of the conic solvers.

Comment: Hey, thanks! But could I ask what is the conic solver? Has it been implemented? I am new to this field...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_optimization